# Can we write- please confirm about your duty

Tags: grammaticality

Can I use -please confirm about your duty.?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without more information. Please edit it to add at least one example of where you want to use this phrase.

Comment: We usually use _confirm_ of specific information - "Please confirm that you will be available for duty on [date] at [time]."

Comment: A question like this might find a better home on ELL sister site FYI @Aaryan